# Jedis Cache implementation without JedisPool/commons-pool2-2.0

Tags: connection, connection-pooling, jedis, java-5

How to implement Jedis without JedisPool/commons-pool2-2.0 because still we are using jdk 1.5(commons-pool2-2.0 does not support JDK 1.5)

How to implement a thread-safe connection pooling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Jedis compatibility with Java 5. You can create your own pooling based on the older [commons-pool 1.6](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-pool%7Ccommons-pool%7C1.6%7Cjar) library. You do not need to have commons-pool2 on your class path to run jedis. I used Jedis 2.7.3 and commons-pool 1.6 to validate the solution approach.

Find the example code attached:

```
import org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool;
import org.apache.commons.pool.PoolableObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;

public class JedisWithOwnPooling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectPool<Jedis> pool = new GenericObjectPool(new JedisFactory("localhost"));

        Jedis j = pool.borrowObject();
        System.out.println(j.ping());

        pool.returnObject(j);

        pool.close();

    }

    private static class JedisFactory implements PoolableObjectFactory<Jedis> {

        private String host;

        /**
         * Add fields as you need. That's only an example.
         */
        public JedisFactory(String host) {
            this.host = host;
        }

        @Override
        public Jedis makeObject() throws Exception {
            return new Jedis(host);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyObject(Jedis jedis) throws Exception {
            jedis.close();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateObject(Jedis jedis) {
            return jedis.isConnected();
        }

        @Override
        public void activateObject(Jedis jedis) throws Exception {
            if (!jedis.isConnected()) {
                jedis.connect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void passivateObject(Jedis jedis) throws Exception {

        }
    }
}
```